# Where can I find the core binaries for v.0.1.5 to v.0.3.21?

Tags: bitcoin-core, client, history

I have been looking for core binaries (i.e. win32-setup.exe & win32.zip & macosx.zip) for earlier clients. Any advice on where they are hosted? They have all been removed from SourceForge.

- https://satoshi.nakamotoinstitute.org/code/ (Only v.0.1.0 to v.0.1.3)
- https://bitcoin.org/en/version-history (Only v.0.3.21 to v.0.20.0)
- https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/releases (Only tar.gz, also not accurate)

Any advice appreciated!

Comment: Related: https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/ju03w9/bitcoin_archaeology_building_old_code_part_ii/

Comment: Cheers :-) Saw in the Dev Mailing List, very cool!

Answer (score 0):

[image: early-releases]

You have the files [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/releases) and can follow the instructions mentioned in below links to build:

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-windows.md

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-osx.md

Comment: This does not answer OP's question I think. You're only giving links to the source code, not the binary releases.

Comment: Couldn't find binaries. There are few threads on Bitcointalk but nothing helpful. Sourceforge is down right now. Not sure what is inside this far file: http://web.archive.org/web/20091129231630/http://sourceforge.net/projects/bitcoin/files/Bitcoin/

Comment: I believe you! But it's still not an answer to the question.